# I want to change the style of all sibling elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using buttons for a tabbed navigation interface. I want to have the active tab red, and the rest black.

```
<div class="tabs">
<button type="button" onclick="selectTab(this);">Astringents</button>
<button type="button" onclick="selectTab(this);">Exfoliators</button>
<button type="button" onclick="selectTab(this);">Moisturizers</button>
</div>

function selectTab(activeTab){
var siblings = activeTab.parentNode.childNodes;
for (s in siblings){
s.style.color='black';
}
activeTab.style.color='red';
```

I am having problems accessing the siblings properly. There are more buttons than these three so I need to solve this dynamically. I will be using Ajax so this page will not reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do extra work... Why not keep a reference to the currently selected tab, then when a new selection is made, reset its style.

Also, it is much better to use CSS classes than inline styles for this (this way, you don't need to muck about with Javascript to change how your tabs look):

```
<style>
  .tab { color: black; }
  .tab-selected { color: red; }
</style>
<div class="tab" onclick="selectTab(this)">Tab 1</div>
<div class="tab" onclick="selectTab(this)">Tab 2</div>
<!-- More tabs -->

<script>
   var selectedTab = null;
   function selectTab(tab) {
     if (selectedTab) { selectedTab.className = 'tab'; }
     tab.className = 'tab-selected';
     selectedTab = tab;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and its cleaner than changing all the siblings for the sake of one.