# Change CSS style in JavaScript when button is clicked but change back to original when another button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page where you click a button with an image of the cursor and the whole HTML body has that cursor:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button id="alias" onclick="cur('alias')"><img src="alais.png"/>
        </button></td>
        <td><button id="cell" onclick="cur('cell')"><img src="cell.png"/>
        </button></td>
        <td><button id="col-resize" onclick="cur('col-resize')"><img src="col-
        resize.png"/>
        </button></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

All the buttons already have a `1px solid black` border
This is the JavaScript function:

```
function cur(curval){
    document.getElementById(curval).style.borderWidth ="3px"
    document.body.style.cursor = curval;
}
```

This is to show which button is selected, but when you press another button the previous button keeps the 3px border. How could I make it so only one button (the most recently pressed one) has the 3px border?

**EDIT**
I have tried [I want to change the style of all sibling elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012655/i-want-to-change-the-style-of-all-sibling-elements) but this uses classes with the same name except one, but I am using IDs and they are all named differently, and I can't work out how you would change this to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to change the style of all sibling elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012655/i-want-to-change-the-style-of-all-sibling-elements)

Comment: @Henry Did you look at my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to previous value and current value and do like this:

```js
var prevElement, currentElement;

function cur(curval) {
  if (!prevElement) {
    prevElement = document.getElementById(curval);
    currentElement = prevElement;
  } else {
    prevElement = currentElement;
    prevElement.style.borderWidth = "1px"
    currentElement = document.getElementById(curval);

  }
  currentElement.style.borderWidth = "3px"
  document.body.style.cursor = curval;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="alias" onclick="cur('alias')">
                    <img src="alais.png" />
                </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="cell" onclick="cur('cell')">
                    <img src="cell.png" />
                </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="col-resize" onclick="cur('col-resize')">
                    <img src="col-
        resize.png" />
                </button>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: How would I change this to have a default value? For example, if I wanted alias to be default so it would have the 3px border when the page is loaded but still change when another button is pressed,

Comment: @Henry In that case you should be able to compare id of the clicked button. If the button clicked has a different id than the last id then you know what to do!

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different approach.

First you add a class to each button (i.e. control-btn) and define css for that class. Then define another active class and make its border width 3px.

So, when you click on button, you just have to switch active class from one button to another.

Here is my idea in nutshell

```js
function cur(curval){
    //find active btn first
    var active_btn = document.querySelector('.control-btn.active');
    
    //if any active btn
    if(active_btn){
     //remove active class from it 
      active_btn.classList.remove('active');
    }
    
    //now add active class to selected button
    document.getElementById(curval).classList.add('active');
    document.body.style.cursor = curval;
}
```

```css
.control-btn{
  border:1px solid black;
}

.control-btn.active{
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="control-btn" id="alias" onclick="cur('alias')"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=alias"/>
        </button></td>
        <td><button class="control-btn" id="cell" onclick="cur('cell')"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=ceil"/>
        </button></td>
        <td><button class="control-btn" id="col-resize" onclick="cur('col-resize')"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=resize"/>
        </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var body = document.body;
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.classList.add("active");
});

reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  cursor: default;
}

body.active {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="button">Click Me</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</body>
```